# C - 'Greater than' vs 'Greater than or equal to' performance

Tags: c, performance

I'm a bit curious about how these comparison operations work underneath the hood, as I'm trying to optimize my code as much as possible and develop good programing habits.

For example, consider the statement

```
0 > 1
```

It should just check if 0 is greater than 1.

But then think about the statement

```
0 >= 1
```

Does it first check if 0 is greater than 1, and then if they are equal?

I'm asking because, if this were the case, wouldn't that also mean that

```
a > b
```

requires half the amount of operations compared to

```
a >= b
```

?

Comment: On most modern architectures all of these different compare operations map to a single instruction. Concentrate mainly on writing readable, maintainable, robust and correct code - micro-optimisations come later (if at all).

Comment: under the hood 101: 1) check generate assembly 2) measure

Comment: Thanks for comments. I'll make sure to put some more trust into my compiler. :)

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @Lobs - Even if it did need an extra comparison, how long do you think that would that take for a 4 GHz processor? How much effort are you prepared to put in to shave off parts of a nanosecond? :-)

Comment: @BoPersson It wasn't so much about one single operation. I was more thinking about loops with millions/billions of iterations and comparisons, and thought that it might save some time if I could reduce the total amount of comparisons by 50%. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is mentioned by others, and [here:](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Branches), most modern processors already have instructions that handle the more complex looking cases you're mentioning.

I'm not sure how far back 'modern' is here, but I would say that if you are worried about performance, this is one place you shouldn't try to optimize for speed; rather for clarity.  An optimizing compiler will typically know a faster way of handling operations than you do.

Comment: Thanks! I'll put some more trust into my compiler then. :)

Comment: It's not just modern processors, most 8-bit micro-controllers have this combined operation and have done for some while.